# Deleted gsp files are still showing up in the built war file

Tags: grails, ggts

I am in the process of reducing our application to a bare minimum for some web service testing.  So I deleted all of the gsp files except for a half dozen related to login or error handling.

I built the project and logged in, and then went to one of the views I deleted.  I was expecting to get a GRE since it could not render the page without the gsp file. Instead the page rendered successfully.  In fact, **all** the views that I had deleted still rendered successfully.

Clearly, something is cached somewhere.  So far, I have cleared out my browser caching (for all my browsers), done a grails clean, verified that the view files were deleted on disk, made sure my work, target and target-eclipse directories were clean.  Checked my ivy cache and verified that it only contained plugin related downloads and had no files from the core application. Checked my WEB-INF.

Suggestions for what else to clean and any pointers to documentation on how the tc-server process works within GGTS would be much appreciated.  (I've googled but not finding what I'm looking for.)

I am out of ideas as to where the cache could be.  What am I missing?  This also brings home to me that I don't really understand how GGTS works with the vfabric-tc-server.... I've worked with IDEA in the past and that actually built a war file that could be moved around. If the vfabric-tc-server builds a war file,  it is not found when I search my windows box.

thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this problem keeps bugging many people like you, so make it a practice to go to target directory and clear all the contents before running `grails war`.

If using linux simply run `rm -rf target/*` followed by `grails war`.

On windows cmd `RD /S /Q folderPath` followed by `grails war`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have modified the defaults in `BuildConfig.groovy`, the 2 most likely suspects are the `target/` directory in your project and the `.grails/` directory below your home directory.